# Rendering a custom tag with a foreign key into templates issues

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-custom-tags

Hi this is the model I am working with

from django.db import models
from users.models import CustomUser

```
class Project(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.PROTECT, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, editable=False)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, editable=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False, null=False, blank=False)
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

The class is populated by an HTML form using this view:

```
def homepage(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    project = Project()
    name = request.POST.get('name')
    total = request.POST.get('total')
    created = datetime.datetime.now()
    user = request.user
    project.user = user
    project.name = name
    project.total = total
    project.created = created
    project.save()
    
    #return HttpResponse(reverse("homepage.views.homepage"))
    return render(request, 'homepage.html')
else:

    return render(request, 'homepage.html')
```

and so I have added a custom tag into my app which is a function

```
@register.filter
def monthlyTotal(user):
    this_month = now().month
    return Project.objects.filter(
        created__month=this_month,
        user=user
        ).aggregate(
        sum_total=Sum('total')
        )['sum_total']
```

I call the tag like this in template

```
 <p>Total monthly sales = {{ user.username|monthlyTotal }}</p>
```

however I get an error saying Field ID expected a number but got 'grandmaster' which is the name of my test user who has multiple Project objects.. if I switch to user.id I get no error but it displays None which makes sense because when I look at my project section in admin the field user is populated by the username not the id so there would be no project where user=id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `user`, not the username, so:

```
<p>Total monthly sales = {{ user|monthlyTotal }}</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this produces the same result as user.id it results in None but the logged in user has multiple projects with a total so it should compute that.. strange.

Comment: @ThiMar: if it is `None`, then that means that there are no records. The `Sum` of no records is not `0`, but `None` to make a distinction between for example `0+0` and the sum of no elements. So for *that* user, there is no `Project` for the `this_month`.

Comment: @ThiMar: note that if you use MySQL and you use `USE_TZ = True` in the settings, you need to add timezone information to your database. Sometimes that is not done automatically, and then filtering "does not work properly". See https://www.django-antipatterns.com/troubleshooting/mysql_can_not_extract_filter_on_attributes_of_a_date_time_object_when_timezones_are_enabled.html

Comment: Oh my! This was a human error last time I did testing on this was last weekend! so November. this works thank you very much for the help!